# Monitor users bank history in realtime using Plaid API

Tags: android, ios, iphone, plaid

We are looking to monitor our users bank history in realtime, in order to build a savings solution similar to Acorn.

We are running into the issue of only have access to user’s information for 30 mins before having to reathenticate. Could we please suggestions as to how to gain realtime access once permission is granted?